# Mime type for Requests post file

Tags: python, python-requests

How do I set the mime type for files (for one file, not for the form) uploaded with Python Requests?

```
import requests
requests.post('http://test.com/upload', files={'data':'123'})
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use tuples and lists to pass additional options for posted files.
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

```
{file_field: (name, content, content_type, additional_file_headers)}
```

So

```
import requests
requests.post('http://test.com/upload', files={'data': ('readme.txt', 'Readme file content or pointer', 'text/plain')})
```

Comment: Updated the answer and documentation https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1886#issuecomment-33461337 :)

Comment: Now for me your answer respects SO standard